# Access call history in app for Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

While it seems [it is not possible for an app to register incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946502/microsoft-teams-incoming-call-event), I wondered if it would be possible to access the call history of the current user?

It looks like [there is a Graph API to get information of a specific call by id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), I didn't find anything about getting the call history or the last call.

This could be a workaround for our approach: We want to enable the employees to make several notes on incoming calls and reference them with existing items in another web application.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Currently, Graph APIs to access call history is not available. I'll check internally for plans.

Comment: Update- This is something that we want to do but not under design or planning as of now. Anticipate this to be taken up for development in 1H20.

Comment: Anything new about the MS Teams call log api?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a new Preview way of and application subscribing to a call event though still no way to get the full history.

> **Application**
>   CallRecords.Read.All:
>   Subscribe to new call records (POST /beta/subscriptions).

There are more details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-callrecords but it suggests you could capture the incoming call and allow notes as you want.