# Call History for MS Teams users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

How to get the call history (Call Detail Record) for a specific user or for all tenant's users using the Microsoft Graph API. It seems impossible and this is a basic functionality for any tenant.
We can see in the Teams' dashboard the call history but we can't get it programmatically to update our database.

Comment: Duplicate of [Access call history in app for Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178558/access-call-history-in-app-for-microsoft-teams).

Comment: @Wajeed - MSFT 1.  you did not answered it.  Please check internally  for your plans and inform me. My question is different . When you have the information in the dashboard, it means that it is in the database. It is super easy to add an API call  (different of the others mentioned in the other question).  Your Team does not have even an export option in the dashboard. We are 20 years back . look the data don't use it.  So my question is not duplicate.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT  an update about the issue?  Did you check internally for plans? roadmap?

Comment: @stefan2410- This is something that we want to do but not under design or planning as of now. Anticipate this to be taken up for development in 1H20.

Comment: @Wajeed - MSFT  So many customers moved to MS Teams an they even can't buy  S4B online user licences.  So you can understand  how frustrated they are. What to answer them in their question "How to get my call history in a csv or json format"?   It is tragic to let them look the MS Teams admin center's call history and  write the calls by hand.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT: Is there an item in user voice related to this?  Also, I agree that this isn't quite a dup, as the linked article discusses in-app access, while this is more about making the call history as seen in the Teams admin console (Users / Calls) available in some way.