# Subscribe to (company-wide) voice call events in O365

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, phone-call, microsoft-teams

We are using O365 for voice calls with MS Teams and want to do some business logic if there is an incoming call.

When searching around the net, there are [lot of information about calling bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calls-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta). But that's not the use case. We do not want to call a bot or get called by a bot, we want to do things in the backend when an employee receives a call from outside the company. Technically it has nothing to do with a bot.

As we can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946502/microsoft-teams-incoming-call-event), it is not possible to write an App for MS Teams, which can subscribe to these events.

Is there ***any*** way to subscribe to call events? For example, could we write a service running on a server which connects and authenticates to Azure to get notifications/events about incoming calls?
Or are there any other solutions?
I mean... there must be something, maybe I just searched for the wrong things, but O365 is normally not a black box and developing things for the company phone system is not uncommon.

Comment: Currently there is no such event available. I will check internally about the plans.